# Checkbox works once but then stops

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Amazing issue with the code below:

```
<head>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('.select-all').click(function() {
            var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
            $(this).closest('section').find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('checked', isChecked);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <section id="sect_1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb_1_1">1.1
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb_1_2">1.2
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb_1_3">1.3
        <input type="checkbox" class="select-all">All
    </section>
    <section id="sect_2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb_2_1">2.1
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb_2_2">2.2
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb_2_3">2.3
        <input type="checkbox" class="select-all">All"
    </section>
</body>
```

1. Clicking the "All" CB of a section checks all other CBs inside this section. As expected
2. Clicking again the "All" CB of a section unchecks all other CBs inside this section. As expected
3. Clicking again the "All" CB of a section DOES NO MORE check all CB inside this section.

Inspected on Chrome and Firefox, I can see the `checked="checked"` attribute appear and disappear inside each `<input type="checkbox" id="cb_x_x">` but without affecting the CB displayed

Any idea?

**EDIT**

Important: the code above do modify the DOM. After clicking, when `.select-all` is checked, all `#cb_x_x` tags within the parent section are updated and inspecting the DOM I can see: `<input type="checkbox" id="cb_x_x" checked="checked">`.

Clicking once again to uncheck `.select-all`, the DOM is also updated: all `#cb_x_x` lose their attribute `checked`.

Continuing and clicking again and again to re-check / re-uncheck `.select-all`, all `#cb_x_x` tags within the parent section are still updated, the `checked="checked"`attribute continues to appear / disappear on all `#cb_x_x` tags within the parent section **but** the display is not updated: all `#cb_x_x` CBs remain *displayed* unchecked even if their attribute `checked="checked"` is added/removed when inspecting the DOM.

Live code available here: http://jsbin.com/orehor/3/

Comment: User .prop() instead of .attr() jQuery 1.6+

Comment: Seems to work for me in FF http://jsbin.com/usujoy/1/edit

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Latest: 1.9. I also use bootstrap, but don't believe this may be a problem.

Comment: some browsers such as IE8 will not find the "section" element

Answer (score 3):

As of jQuery 1.6 for modifying properties of the elements `prop` method should be used instead of `attr`, also you don't need `each` method, jQuery calls `each` internally.

```
$(function() {
   $('.select-all').change(function() {
      $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
      // $(this).closest('section').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this tomorrow. But still cannot figure out why it works at step 1 and 2 but no more at step 3 and after.

Comment: @MaxEvron This works for older browsers (no section) and for newer jQuery - uses prop. see here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2011/06/html-difference-between-attribute-and.html so it works in 1.9 version forward also. note that `siblings('input:checkbox')` works also.

Comment: @MaxEvron Because after setting `checked` attribute, `checked` becomes a property and modifying attributes doesn't changed the properties.

Comment: +1 for not using .each and using .prop.  Perhaps it should be .change however to ensure it captures all methods it might get changed.

Comment: The code above does not work. Clicking on a `.select-all` CB calls the `.change()` event but `$(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]')` returns no element. Same thing after fixing the syntax to `$(this).closest('section').siblings('input[type=checkbox]')` (need to check all CBs within the parent section.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix: use prop() instead of attr(). Backward compatibility with JQuery 1.6+ is broken. See http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.select-all').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('section').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
</script>
```